# Pl/SQL display results of select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Set ServerOutput on size 100000;
declare
countTab number := 0;
countCol number := 0;
currDate varchar2(30);
scale number := 0;


Begin

select count(*) into countCol from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'EVAPP_INTERFACE' and COLUMN_NAME = 'TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM' and DATA_SCALE is null; 
IF  (countCol <> 0) then   

 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  EVAPP_INTERFACE.TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM values begin'); 
 execute immediate 'select APPSEQNO, TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM from evapp_interface where TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM > 999999999999';

END IF;
END;
\
```

I am trying to display the results of the select query.  I tried running just the select statements as is, but it gives an exception saying it can't find the columns mentioned. So, I tried putting the table name infront of the columns, and it complained that I needed to use `INTO` , and I used that as well, but still it did not like the syntax.

Comment: and DATA_SCALE is null ?? That's not a column of table USER_TAB_COLUMNS

Comment: @Nathan - [yes it is](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_5459.htm); 'Digits to the right of the decimal point in a number'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL*Plus, the simplest option is probably to do something like

```
Set ServerOutput on size 100000;
variable rc refcursor;
declare
  countTab number := 0;
  countCol number := 0;
  currDate varchar2(30);
  scale number := 0;
Begin
  select count(*) 
    into countCol 
    from USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
   where TABLE_NAME = 'EVAPP_INTERFACE' 
     and COLUMN_NAME = 'TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM' 
     and DATA_SCALE is null; 
  IF  (countCol <> 0) then   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('  EVAPP_INTERFACE.TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM values begin'); 
    open :rc 
     FOR 'select APPSEQNO, TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM ' ||
         '  from evapp_interface ' ||
         ' where TARGET_AMNT_LTV_NUM > 999999999999';
  END IF;
END;
/

PRINT rc;
```

If you want to display the result from PL/SQL, you'd need to open the cursor, fetch the results into local variables, and then do something with the local variables such as writing them to `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

Comment: if I have other sql blocks where I am checking for other columns, do I use a different cursor? Or can I use the same one, and print everything in the end?

Comment: @roymustang86 - I'm not sure that I understand the question.  A cursor is a pointer to a query.  If you are stating that you need to execute multiple dynamic queries and you want to print the results from each of the queries after you have executed many anonymous PL/SQL blocks, you'd need to declare multiple `refcursor` variables in SQL*Plus.  If you are just going to execute an anonymous block, print the results, execute another anonymous block, print the results, etc. then you can use a single `refcursor` variable in SQL*Plus.

Comment: I did what you said, but after 8 cursors, it gives me the error saying cursor is closed. ALso, does Oracle take care to close the cursors at the end of a script?

Comment: @roymustang86 - you're opening the cursor inside an `if` block; if you don't go into that block the cursor won't be opened, so that may be what you're seeing. You could do an `else` that opens the cursor for something else, e.g. `open :rc for 'select ''count was zero'' from dual`. And yes, the cursors won't survive the script.